# Call a function that overrides a builtin command inside another function

Tags: linux, bash

In `bashrc` I'm overwriting the builtin `cd` to do some wrapper operations and checks.

```
 function cd {
      builtin cd $@
      pwd=$(pwd)
      user_color
      if [  "$pwd" == "$BRA" ] ; then
         ....
      fi
     }
```

Later, I want to call in a different function my `cd function` but it is calling the `builtin cd` instead.

```
function check(){
  cd $BRA
  ..... do something else
}
```

Comment: Are you running `check` from your interactive shell or a script? Scripts don't inherit shell functions by default. You need to export the function.

Comment: Your code is missing quotes in in several important places.  Run it through [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find out where they are.

Comment: @Barmar both functions are in bashrc; what the check function does  is `cd` in a folder and set some paths;  the cd function is used also outside, but check only once when bashrc is executed. cd is setting some clues in prompt based on the location.

Comment: If both functions are defined in the same shell then it should work.